# Configure DD-WRT router as a network switch with services

Tags: networking, router, dd-wrt

I've had a Linksys WRT54GS running DD-WRT (build 14929) for a while. I recently bought another Linksys (Cisco) router (WRT160NL) and installed DD-WRT on it (build 16785).

I'd like to keep the WRT54GS as my main router since it is very stable and use the WRT160NL as a network switch, NAS device, and asterisk server.

I already have samba installed, configured, and running fine on the 160. However, the 160 is running as a router so only devices connected to it can access network shares.

How can I configure the 160 so that all devices in my network can access its network shares?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the Setup, Basic Setup tab, turn the WAN connection type to Disabled.  The under WAN Port, check Assign WAN port to Switch.  Save and Apply settings.

Comment: hmmm, looks like the router can no longer access the internet. When I ssh into the router and attempt to run commands like `wget`, or `opkg update`, I get errors relating to download failures... Any ideas?

Comment: The router cannot access the internet or things attached to it?  You need to assign the router an IP address on your network so it knows where it is.

Comment: Correction, the router can ping ip addresses but it just can not resolve host names. `ping -c 4 google.com` fails with `ping: bad address` but `ping -c 4 74.125.226.9` works. So its a DNS issue. FWIW, I made sure to give the router an IP address, and a DNS gateway address.

Comment: Thanks, I added the gateway address to the "Local DNS" and it now works.

Comment: Is there a way to log in and change settings after doing this or do you have to reset the router?

Comment: If you assign it an IP address, use that to log in.  If you didn't then you likely have to reset it.